# Does anyone else have a bizarre Visual Studio 2010 code-editing problem when style="" attribute?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

In Visual Studio 2010 (just upgraded), in standard Web Application projects (everything) I cannot finish writing `<element style="">`. Text input is impossible as soon as I get to `style="` . Some kind of text editor bug.

Is there a fix?

**EDIT:** I've noticed this seems related to having horizontal/vertical Tab Groups open.

Comment: Here's a page with some known issues for VS2010 Beta and hotfixes : http://blogs.msdn.com/wpfsldesigner/archive/2010/02/15/know-issues-for-visual-studio-2010-release-candidate.aspx

Answer (score 0):

@rlb: There is no mention of anything related to this issue on that MSDN blog page...

@Joel: I have the same issue as you.  Are you by chance using Resharper?  I am, and my colleages who are *not* using it don't have this problem.  Check out [this page](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/RSRP-188526?query=100%25).

My work-around (until I find something better) is to copy the element with all its attributes from Visual Studio to a text editor, edit the style attribute in the text editor, then copy the whole thing back to Visual Studio, pasting over the still-selected element.  Not exactly the most elegant, but better than not being able to edit inline styles — or giving up resharper...

Answer (score 0):

My current work-around:

1. Format code (CTRL-K,D)
2. Undo

**FIX: Installing Visual Studio 2010 SP1 has not fixed the issue.**
EDIT: Formatting code does not always work. Perhaps it is a content encoding issue.